# Is it possible to do: user = User.find(234234) and somehow ignore some columns in the select query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some columns that contain a large amount of data (text, etc), and sometimes I am just displaying a summary list of the rows and I don't want to fetch all that data.

Is there an option to exclude certain columns?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the columns from the select clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can *exclude* certain columns, but you can have ActiveRecord return only specific columns using the `:select` parameter, e.g.

```
@articles = Article.find( :all, :select => ‘created_at, title, summary’ )
```

Comment: Yeah, you are looking for `:select =>`

Comment: And in Rails 3, you could also do `Article.select('created_at, title, summary').all`.

Answer (score 1):

you can find by sql query so you can fetch your required data and its easy

Post.find_by_sql("SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date)